# Error in ORACLE SQL MERGE STATEMENT

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to execute following code in Oracle 11g, and encountering to error..

```
MERGE INTO EMP_COPY4 C
USING (SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.EMAIL, E.COMMISSION_PCT FROM EMPLOYEES) E
ON (C.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
C.FIRST_NAME = E.FIRST_NAME,
C.LAST_NAME = E.LAST_NAME,
C.EMAIL = E.EMAIL,
C.COMMISSION_PCT = E.COMMISSION_PCT
DELETE WHERE (E.COMMISSION_PCT IS NOT NULL)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES (E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.EMAIL, E.COMMISSION_PCT);
```

EMP_COPY4 is a copy table of EMPLOYEES and has only following columns EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, COMMISSION_PCT

I TRY TO MERGE THEM ON CERTAIN CONDITIONS, BUT ORACLE GIVES FOLLOWING ERROR

```
Error starting at line : 405 in command -
MERGE INTO EMP_COPY4 C
USING (SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.EMAIL, E.COMMISSION_PCT FROM EMPLOYEES) E
ON (C.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
C.FIRST_NAME = E.FIRST_NAME,
C.LAST_NAME = E.LAST_NAME,
C.EMAIL = E.EMAIL,
C.COMMISSION_PCT = E.COMMISSION_PCT
DELETE WHERE (E.COMMISSION_PCT IS NOT NULL)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES (E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.EMAIL, E.COMMISSION_PCT)
Error at Command Line : 406 Column : 66
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "E"."COMMISSION_PCT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Line 405 is start of statement, line 406 is second line.

Can you please help me to figure out why such error comes...?

Comment: your alias E needs to be inside the bracket..

Comment: And give that subquery another alias

Comment: Or change the USING clause to `USING (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, COMMISSION_PCT FROM EMPLOYEES) E`. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @Shankar moving alias E into brackets didn't worked same error.

Comment: @Mihai gave alternative alias also didn't worked.

Comment: @BobJarvis, YES its worked thanks you! That means that in brackets oracle doesn't recognize alias... using MERGE and USING statements

Comment: You put the alias outside the subselect, which means the alias applies to the results of the subselect but is not visible inside the subselect. You could also do it like this: `USING (SELECT X.EMPLOYEE_ID, X.FIRST_NAME, X.LAST_NAME, X.EMAIL, X.COMMISSION_PCT FROM EMPLOYEES X) E`. Here you can see that the alias `X` is visible to the subselect but the alias `E` is not. Now, just for fun - you can use the alias `E` twice: `USING (SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.EMAIL, E.COMMISSION_PCT FROM EMPLOYEES E) E`, but note that there are TWO `E` aliases, and they're different. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace 2-d line with
either

```
USING (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, COMMISSION_PCT FROM EMPLOYEES) E
```

or

```
USING (SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.EMAIL, E.COMMISSION_PCT FROM EMPLOYEES E) E
```

You can not use alias in SELECT list if table is not aliased

Comment: Yes its worked! thanks. first time to see that we can use alias inside brackets, than again outside of brackets, but it works.

Comment: You may use different aliases inside and outside brackets to avoid confusing. 
But same alias also works fine. 
Inner alias works inside brackest, outer alias - outside.